# PHP - fputcsv when filename NOT in_array

Tags: php, filesystems, string-comparison

I have previously iterated thru a filesystem and uploaded a large number of files whose filename's matched a string and all the matched strings are in an array.

I am now trying to iterate thru that same file system to output a csv file of all the file's that did NOT get uploaded on the first pass.

```
// The SPL object is working fine here; problem is in my logic below ...
$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path);

foreach($it as $file){
    $filename = $file->getFilename();
    $uploaded_filenames = ['face', 'arm', 'leg'];

    foreach($uploaded_filenames as $up){
        if(strpos($filename, $up) !== false {
            // do nothing!
        }else{
            fputcsv($handle, $filename);
        }
    }
}
```

Just looking for a more /correct/elegant way of doing this

Thank you Orangepill, that just about worked. The exact syntax:

```
$in_array = false;
foreach($this->uploaded_filenames as $whatever){

    if(strpos($filename, $whatever) !== false){
        $in_array = true;
        break;
    }

}

if(!$in_array) fputcsv($handle, $fullpath);
```

Thanks again!

Comment: Just adding quickly, you can assume every other part of outputting the file (ob_clean etc) is working. The file is outputting fine, just not giving me the filenames I need.

Comment: The key here was setting a boolean value outside the foeach so you weren't depending on the return value of PHP's strpos ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is

```
$inArray = false;
foreach($uploaded_filenames as $up){
    if(strpos($filename, $up) !== false) {
        $inArray = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (!$inArray)){
    fputcsv ($handle, $filename);    
}
```

instead of

```
foreach($uploaded_filenames as $up){
        if(strpos($filename, $up) !== false) {
            // do nothing!
        }else{
            fputcsv($handle, $filename);
        }
}
```

Comment: Another case where the answer is right there in the question title. Never ceases to amaze me.

Comment: Actually, I was simplifying the question a bit, so that didn't work. The strings in the array only contained portions of the filename i.e. friend trip face.jpg ... that's why I was using strpos to begin with. I trimmed back my code example a bit too much, sorry

Comment: the problem with your code was that you where writing for every mismatch so the only way you would not get a line written is if your file contained face arm and leg in it.